# When I run my dotnet server in docker I get socket hang up error

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I have a dotnet project and when I ran it inside docker container the build goes right and the program starts (it logs that everything is fine), but when I make a request in postman, I got a socket hang up error. what can be a reason? When I manually start a server by dotnet run command it works fine.

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["kisc.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "./kisc.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "kisc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "kisc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "kisc.dll"]
```

And the containers logs

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

Comment: Maybe https://medium.com/it-dead-inside/docker-containers-and-localhost-cannot-assign-requested-address-6ac7bc0d042b

Comment: @MichaelMao after reading your link. I had the same issue as OP. Changing the listener from localhost:5000 to :5000 resolved the issue for me.

Comment: @AkezhanOb1 Did you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you are here looking for and answer for .net8 and getting the error with the command:

```
docker run -p 1414:80 dotnetapi
```

apparently there is a new default port (8080) for .net 8, so now you will have to run it like this:

```
docker run -p 1414:8080 dotnetapi
```

Where the first -p flag is {external_port}:{internal_port} and 'dotnetapi' is your docker container

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the default url in your app?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "https://localhost:8001");
            });
}
```

Or Set Enviroment With port in your dockerfile

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS = "http://localhost:5000"
```

Look [Here](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/)

Comment: In .NET 6 it would be like `builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => {
    options.ListenAnyIP(5000);
});`

Answer (score 0):

in `.Net 8` Deafult Http Port Changed To `8080`

if you are using `Docker-Compose`  you shoud set Port Fowarding in `docker-compose.override.yml` file as follows :

```yml
version: '3.4'
    
services:

  serviceName:
    container_name: containerName
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
    ports:
      - "8000:8080" #map 8080 port to 8000 local port
```

also you can change default port by setting  `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS` Environment variable

```yml
version: '3.4'
    
services:

  serviceName:
    container_name: containerName
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development 
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS=8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```